# C# access data from COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, com+, comadmin

Earlier I was using code as below to grab COM+ applications and verify that my app is running

```
COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog catalog = new COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogClass();
catalog.Connect(servername);
catalog.GetCollection("Applications")
```

Now I need to perform the same actions but from other domain. So when I try to run the code above I receive authentication error.
I have tried to connect via WMI and grab list of COM+ applications from win32 wmi providers, but it seems that it's either not possible or I am doing smth wrong.

I would be pleased if someone could help me to get the list of applications from COMAdminCatalog using credentials.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but please just verify that using the actual IP address of the server when connecting is also failing (instead of servername).

Comment: Yes, it also results in authentication error as it tries to authenticate with user I'm logged in with and it does not have admin rights in target domain.
For ex:
I am running from: ADomain\John.Smith - admin in ADomain
Target PC: BDomain\J_Smith - admin in BDomain
That is why I am trying to find a way for remote authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to impersonate a different user on the current thread.

```
using (ImpersonatedUser user = new ImpersonatedUser("USER_NAME", "DOMAIN_NAME", "USER PASSWORD"))
{

    COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog objCatalog = new COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog();
    objCatalog.Connect("SERVER_NAME");

    COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogCollection objAppCollection =
        (COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogCollection) objCatalog.GetCollection("Applications");

    objAppCollection.Populate();

}
```

For more details:

- `ImpersonatedUser` class: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joncole/2009/09/21/impersonation-code-in-c/
- `How to impersonate`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2005/03/21/how-to-impersonate/